# std::vector< std::vector<elem> > или std::list< std::vector<elem> >, как удалить элемент контейнера при итерации по нему?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std-list

В общем, использован `std::vector< std::vector<string> >` и нужно удалить из этого вектора элемент при итерации по нему же, то есть, к примеру, так:

```
std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >  data;
for ( std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >::iterator  it = data.begin ();
      it != data.end (); ++it)
{
  // Тут много сравнений элементов этого вектора с входными данными функции,
  // и в одном из сравнений происходит удаление
  if ( (*it)[0] == something )
    it = data.erase (it);

  if ( it == data.end () )
    break;
}
```

До этого я, вообще, писал так:

```
std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >  data;
for ( std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >::iterator  it = data.begin ();
      it != data.end (); ++it)
{
  // Тут много сравнений элементов этого вектора с входными данными функции,
  // и в одном из сравнений происходит удаление
  if ( (*it)[0] == something )
  {
    data.erase (it);
    break;
  }

}
```

И мне это сходило с рук, пока не убрал `break` в схожем коде и словил краш. Потом долго искал причину и нашёл, что это из-за инвалидации итераторов.

Но теперь причина ясна (плохо читал учебники), а как правильно писать никто не показал. Хотя были всевозможные варианты обхода, из которых мне подошла проверка на конец, чтобы не было краша при итерации за конец контейнера.

Ясно, что тут, скорей всего, нужно видеть код, чтобы что-то посоветовать. Но так, в целом, что нужно использовать, если нужно удалить элемент контейнера при итерации по этому контейнеру?

Что-то на подобие `remove_if` и прочее, что советовали другим, мне не подошло, хотя возможно я не вник должным образом. 
Ну, и за `std::list` или `std::vector`, я остановился на `std::list< std::vector<std::string> >`, так как мне нужно проходить по листу только для поиска или вставки/удаления, а по вектору именно для произвольного доступа, так как я знаю под каким индексом лежит нужный мне элемент.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что нужно последовательно просматривать элементы вектора и удалять некоторые из них?

--

Если направление не важно (скорее даже, если решение об удалении элемента не требует анализа следующих элементов вектора), то двигайтесь от конца к началу.

     for (int i = vec.size; i >= 0; i--) 
       if (need_to_delete(vec, i))
         vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);

Но учтите, что это м.б. крайне неэффективно, поскольку .erase() вызывает [перестроение вектора](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
vector<T> data; // T может быть vector<string> или любой другой тип
//
for (auto iter = data.begin(); iter != data.end(); /* ничего */)
{
    // какая-то логика
    if (надо удалять)
        iter = data.erase(iter);
    else
        iter++;
}
```

Comment: @VladD, интересно, оптимизатор 

(будет ли `data.end()` вызываться на каждой итерации или только один раз а начале)

тут не помешает?

Comment: @avp: Нет, он покамест скорее слишком глупый чем слишком умный :( Поэтому общий совет об итерации с конца всё ещё валиден.

Но на самом деле лучше пользоваться стандартной идиомой `erase`/[`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: Хм, а за что минус?

Answer (score 2):

> оптимизатор тут не помешает?

Как-то смотрел оптимизацию циклов в `MSVS` в базовой конфигурации релиза: `end` запоминается в начале, чтобы в итерациях сравнивать указатели, не вызывая повторный `end` (хотя и не отрицаю, что мог просто соптимизировался сам `end`).

как вариант - проходить массив **в обратном порядке**, без участия итератора:

```
for( size_t i = data.size() ; i-- ; ){
  if( надо удалять ){
    data.erase( data.begin() + i );
  }
}
```

или с участием (для списков, например):

```
auto It = data.rbegin();
for( size_t i = data.size() ; i-- ; ){
  auto rIt = It++;
  if( надо удалять rIt ){
    data.erase( --( rIt.base() ) );
  }
}
```

> Но учтите, что это м.б. крайне неэффективно, поскольку .erase() вызывает перестроение вектора

без "перестроений", но **с перестановками** (для [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)):

```
auto It = data.rbegin();
auto endIt = data.end();
for( size_t i = data.size() ; i-- ; ){
  auto rIt = It++;
  if( надо удалять rIt ){
    std::swap( *rIt, *( --endIt ) );
  }
}
data.erase( endIt, data.end() );
```

вместо `swap`, конечно можно использовать `copy`, если это принципиально

Comment: >то двигайтесь от конца к началу

пардон, avp, не заметил Ваш комментарий